# calling java method in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I want to call java class method in my javascript page:

My java class method:

```
public static String getAccessToken() {
    //OAuth2Details oauthDetails  = new OAuth2Details();
    System.out.println("Test OAuth");
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("vvv");}
```

I tried,my jsp is:

```
<% System.out.println("inside java");%>
 <%OAuthUtils ex = new OAuthUtils(); %>
 <%=ex.getAccessToken()%>
```

But, it returns null.Could anyone please suggest me as how should I call method in javascript

Comment: Where is the javascript?

Comment: The method doesn't even compile, it's weird that you get `null`.

Comment: if return type is a `String` why use java code in jsp? why don't you make an ajax call?

Comment: @realuser404,i have pasted part of jsp page

Comment: @BHAGYASHRIGAIKWAD you know jsp and javascript are not the same thing right?

Comment: @realuser404,taht was typo,@Jordi,I am not sure as how to use ajax for this small issue-only calling java function and retrieve string value. example to demonstrate same will help!

Comment: Your method is a static method so no need to create an object for that just do `OAuthUtils. getAccessToken()`.

Comment: @karthikeyan,I tried with that , but its not working,thats y created instance ,its not even printing sysout statement in console

Comment: @BHAGYASHRIGAIKWAD `OAuthUtils. getAccessToken()` is returning null. Plese debug and check.

Comment: its working now, I removed static word from my class, however, now I am getting error while running code as : `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated` , any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The basics, using `JQuery` will be like this:

```
$.get( "/mapping/url/getAccessToken",{  } ).done(function( data ) {
    if (data != null) {
        // do your stuff
    } else {
        // show error message or whatever
    }
});
```

Of course, to get the correct result, you must tell Java to map this method to be accessible through the `AJAX` call.

With Spring use `@RequestMapping` annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mapping/url/getAccessToken")
public String getAccessToken() {
    //OAuth2Details oauthDetails  = new OAuth2Details();
    System.out.println("Test OAuth");
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("vvv");

    if (success) {
        return "what you need";
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you don't have Spring in your app, extending `HttpRequest::doGet()`. 
[Check here a tutorial of `AJAX-HttpRequest` call](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/04/jquery-ajax-request-response-java.html).

## ADD-ON

**Why no scripts should be written in JSPs – Java**
Here is why one should avoid using scriplets in JSPs:

- JSP Scriptlets reduces the maintainability and readibility of the code and hence making it difficult to read and make further changes.
- JSP Scriptlets can not be re-used.
- JSP Scriptlets are not unit-testable.
- JSP Scriplets merge the presentation with business logic which is highly prone to errors.
- Last but not least, if JSP Scriptlets throws an exception, it breaks the whole page there and doesn’t move further in the processing.

[From this article](http://thewebplant.com/why-no-scripts-should-be-written-in-jsps-java/)